# Как получить имя класса PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Как в родительском классе получить имя класса, который вызвал действие?

Пример:

```
class ParentClass {
    function action() {
        echo $className;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {}

$parentClass = new ParentClass();
$parentClass->action();     // ParentClass

$childClass = new ChildClass();
$childClass->action();      // ChildClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_class](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-class.php):

```
echo get_class($this);
```

для статики - [get_called_class()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-called-class.php)

Answer (score 3):

Существуют так называемые **"Волшебные константы"**, о которых можно почитать в официальном [мануале](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php).
Для решения вашей задачи определите метод, в котором возвращаете `__CLASS__` , либо, как написал Etki - `get_class($this)`.

```
class ParentClass {
    function action() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

Метод вернет полное название класса вместе с пространством имен. Чтобы получить только имя класса, можно разбить строку по `\` и взять последний элемент.

```
class ParentClass {
    function action() {
        $array = explode('\\', __CLASS__);
        return $array[count($array) - 1];
    }
}
```